# Alternative to nested AWK arrays?

Tags: arrays, awk

file1 is

```
foo"blahblah#AAA17"blahblah
foo"blahblah#BBB64"blahblah
foo"blahblah#CCC53"blahblah
foo"blahblah#DDD59"blahblah
foo"blahblah#EEE22"blahblah
foo"blahblah#FFF49"blahblah
```

file2 is tab-separated and is

```
AAA17   something9197
BBB64   something333
CCC53   something268
DDD59   something5050
EEE22   something4643
FFF49   something2
```

I want to add some text to each of the lines in file1. The text will include field 2 from file2, as shown below. Using gawk I can get the desired result with nested arrays:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR {arr1[$1]=$2; next} {split($0,arr2,"#|\"")} {print $0": moomoo "arr1[arr2[3]]}' file2 file1
foo"blahblah#AAA17"blahblah: moomoo something9197
foo"blahblah#BBB64"blahblah: moomoo something333
foo"blahblah#CCC53"blahblah: moomoo something268
foo"blahblah#DDD59"blahblah: moomoo something5050
foo"blahblah#EEE22"blahblah: moomoo something4643
foo"blahblah#FFF49"blahblah: moomoo something2
```

Is there a simple way to do this that does not involve nested arrays?

Note that the two files might have their lines shuffled - not in order as shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{arr[$1]=$2;next} {print $0 ": moomoo", arr[$3]}' file2 FS='[#"]' file1
foo"blahblah#AAA17"blahblah: moomoo something9197
foo"blahblah#BBB64"blahblah: moomoo something333
foo"blahblah#CCC53"blahblah: moomoo something268
foo"blahblah#DDD59"blahblah: moomoo something5050
foo"blahblah#EEE22"blahblah: moomoo something4643
foo"blahblah#FFF49"blahblah: moomoo something2
```

Comment: many thanks, I didn't know you could set field separators separately for the 2 files in this way.

Comment: Yes setting variables to different initial values between files is one of the very few legitimate reasons to set a variable in the file list area rather than setting them up front with `-v var=value`. In GNU awk you could alterantively set them in the `BEGINFILE` section, and in any awk you can always do `FNR==1 { FS='whatever'; $0=$0 }`. The `$0=$0` is to force awk to re-split the record into fields using the new FS value.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks quite good already, assuming the files aren't too large. "Nested arrays" is not time-penalizing the way "nested loops" are. But there is a another way to do it using the builtin `join`, although I don't know if I'd call it "simpler":

```
cat file1|awk -F"#|\"" '{print $3,$0": moomoo"}'|sort >file3
sort file2|join file3 -|cut -d " " -f 2-
```